# Boost converter output does not match sim

Tags: voltage, ltspice, simulation, boost, voltage-measurement

I'm experimenting with a simple boost converter. However, the measured output value on the breadboard is nowhere near what I expect :

[image]

Simulation in LTspice gives about 4.5V while I'm measuring about 2.8V, even less than the input. Am I doing something wrong?

(Eventually, I would like to build a booster from 5V to 27V providing 30mA. Is it even possible with this kind of design?)

Comment: This should work. How are you driving the transistor? What diode are you using? What's the current rating and actual inductance of your inductor?

Comment: The transistor should be driven by a square wave, not a sine. The base current must be sufficient to properly saturate the transistor, e.g. bring the collector node close to the ground during the on-time. If you select a 50-kHz square wave with a 3-V amplitude during 10 µs (0 V the rest of the time), then the duty ratio \$D\$ defined as \$\frac{t_{on}}{T_{sw}}\$ is 50% implying a *theoretical* output voltage equal to \$V_{out}=V_{in}\frac{1}{1-D}\$.

Comment: Function generator from the scope, diode is 1N4001. As for the inductor, i'm not sure as i scrounged it from an other circuit. Stripes on it read 220u.

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes I know, i tried it too and the problem is the same. What puzzles me is the difference in reading of sim/real.

Comment: What do you observe at the junction diode anode/transistor collector and what frequency did you try? The best is not use a bipolar transistor but logic-level MOSFET if driven from the 3-V source. Also, very important, what is the dc resistance of the inductor?

Comment: @VerbalKint It looks like a degraded square wave, with spikes on both end of the wave. I tried 50kHz. DCR is 3 Ohms

Comment: Measure DCR ESR or give LC part numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *diode is 1N4001*

Oops, that's a poor choice (even at 10 kHz switching speed).

You need something that has low reverse recovery time and the 1N400x diode is appalling beyond compare. Try a fast diode like a [1N5819](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88525/1n5817.pdf) rectifier - OK it's a bit big than a 1N400x but, if your switching frequency is anything like above 25 kHz then it's probably wise to use something that has low forward volt drop and is fast. There are plenty to choose from and you needn't go for Schottky types either if you want 27 volts out.

Anyway, with a 10 kHz switching frequency you should be aiming for something roughly like this: -

[image]

- Input voltage is 3 volts
- Output is 27 volts
- Load is 1000 Ω
- Inductance is 47 μH

This is operating in DCM due to the high load resistance. If the load dipped down to (say) 50 Ω then it might look like this: -

[image]

Now it's running in CCM so, take heed about the duty cycles involved to regulate the output voltage. In CCM a duty of 88.9% is needed until it drops into DCM (higher load resistance of about 86 Ω).

Anyway feel free to plug in some values on [my crappy website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) and try and figure out what suits you best. No charge of course.

<sub>Please note that I'm not trying to encourage anyone to visit my website. I built it purely to learn about JavaScript programming, HTML and messing around - please do not feel any obligation to use it at all - I don't need the traffic and I'm not trying to get paid for adverts on it either. It is what it is; a site full of random stuff that is slowly evolving and fairly specific to some of my personal interests.</sub>

> *Am I doing something wrong?*

I'd use a MOSFET instead of a BJT and, I'd make sure that the inductor series resistance is not too high and that saturation currents are significantly higher than those predicted on the simulation above.

> *Eventually, I would like to build a booster from 5V to 27V providing
> 30mA*

Well it's going to be operating in DCM (not that big of a deal) with those parameters: -

[image]

But, it can certainly run a 100 Ω load in CCM: -

[image]

Comment: The 1N400x diodes don't have appalling reverse recovery times!  At least not if you're trying to use them as cheap PIN RF switching diodes.  For power applications, though -- yes, they're _slow_.

Comment: @TimWescott haha

Comment: Ah, yes, that's much better thank you. I'll try to output 27V now and see if i can find a mosfet somewhere. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Change the diode too and, check the inductor spec. Also drive the mosfet with a decent gate source voltage and, make sure it’s a rectangular wave and not sine. Be also aware that this is a q and a site and not a progressive tutoring site so please, respect the fact that comments are limited. Make the most of them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to boost output voltage by some gain ratio. input current must also increase by the same ratio with margin for losses.

In the end, I'll show you how to get a boost of 10x Vin=3V with DCR=1 ohm Rb= 68 ohms and ESR of 47uF = 100 mohms.  Operating from a 3.3V logic output is possible with this range of impedance then direct connect to base is possible with small Pd in the driver.  You will want to have some voltage regulation in you design spec.

There are several design issues:

1. No Component specs #1 issue.

- Inductors rated for your input current range of 500 mA must be amplified by at least the output current with 50% margin for losses and saturation.
- If your boost ratio is Av=10 and Iout = 30mA then L must be at least rated for 30mA x 10 x 1/50% = 600 mA and that's just the average current, not the peak. The current limit spec determines the conductor size and core and will have an T=L/R ratio of around 22 us to 220 us time constant. This will affect also your switching frequency choice. That means for L= 220 uH,  perhaps DCR=1 to 10 ohms. Yours is possibly at the high end where all your losses occur.
- going for a lower boost ratio of 4.5 to 30 V will be easier (Av< 7)

2. Most likely low Q lossy parts for L, C. L current peak is ILmax=Vin / (DCR+Rce or RdsOn) =3V/1ohm= 3A or 3V/10 ohms only 300 mA
3. Insufficient base bias current for Ic/Ib = 10 to 20 to get saturated .
4. Test Design Specs
5. Inconsistent schematic and test conditions,
6. no duty cycle given.
7. Theory works if your model matches the actual parts.
8. In practice, your assumptions need to be improved.
9. No design details like Vce, IL(t)
10. No feedback regulation

In order to get the 3V supply to boost to 30V, it is much harder but possible.  The ideal duty cycle for a boost of 10 is 90% but with losses, you will find you need ~ 95% duty cycle.

What I suggest is when looking at each component selected is to determine the impedance of each at DC and operating frequency and harmonics.

[Here I have simulated 3 cases logically](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATOB0AMYHYCcYCsBmWSAs2BsEq2ApgLQIirRLrYRKqzp4LpISwAclslIblMmDAAoAGYhSSPCAgRsk7NzkL0UMNFSyRAJRDT9MpYZC9e2XulPXYmkQBtZXE4RkGzcWLDmnoEPHi4bFyoeLAWeFqwIgAmsqHguPwciQpQMcRiAIYArvYALiIA7rIIUK7xMhXRJRV1CRzc0QDmlW11ZTYiAE4guNxgSf1tvGBeNX3GFRa81cXJo0NeqeAiAPKTA0MGgwpgpiIAbuAQygmQA%20zWUJgIyxpaDzbU8JzzF%200NCdEcSAsralGVw843CFHo0BYeE46FCuEITD%20ti8%201E%20Scl3K52B4F80No2CIEEwBAgYE4ClsCEJ-lgqDudDwSFgeCsY14GWyeUKvUasnk4DCGOs0J6wo%20YCFwigozFmDSAognWqvlEJRmK2GuwOJWYZxk6GYIxEAAdNprjNLcZSRABlE7cHZC9yyEDZewAZ2IuPQdv%20YCugP5lNd7q9Pvezqqznc8yDKn%20c16hqqAr1I0okLjKQ6WJkE3jCRTxt5zkCgt4nDM4Gi9olV0lQJloaynu9%2019vUb4CufIDzdC0S7UoQ0YGQtG43mfaFfeB0%20c-eFCYmfPLfNjtRjY4dOra2oqsYAHiA8JLZJwtJw0BfuHsFABVAByOgAogBBAAyAB0Pb-YL%2034AI6-gAIgAwjoAA0r62tBv46AARsBYAANYiCeZ5-PIWjINhxj3iAABC76gb%20AASACWzQABZgZBUG-rB8EekhKHoZhKRBpeVhqFYhFEcQ%20T5MQ3QAFyAR6n4APZFPRLHMYxrHIUB0K-tJNEALYen6RBpJ09JVJ0sxuq24YdvMhltGEygWHuNmlFAVlKjK8wOfKlCjreBwnqgZL8LCp4sgFd41iAADG9iUeFqG-h6RSUfk4V0R60kmvklHSQAdjpJR6Y5lBJPIZiWUVBlJB5EwahU6ZJgViBGeUziyrU5xeRU2rRBYVikFa57nlW1hgAA%20pww0IMNYCwjQSDDagw22CNeCTcNEB2OFAUyFaLmniGYBCCC8C%20CiIjoHcJg7KcJiogc3WSFaToVtYE2BONk3TegY1jAt0AjbAK1rfNaG-p%20aykRh%20iYuAkA9loew3AAahDaB3qmfzYOjgogBBOi-mI0ndCDyPMrILB9JwyjnQofy-vYslMXBklkOFWQmkpv4ACrAb%20YC-vk0mSWMOR-h6pC-gAkqBH4-qLv62vkMTQL%20zOsyLAB8v4cLAwu-pRWV8zRlEi90WRZc0xDI4F8jghg8TmFjbEevjhMeh6WT5DkJsZdlIjSdDfTWBgCDnVEv3XP7vp%202MAdAmoJMQmU0JhNgkCvGSMqeEdqK%20-wW35vwo60H0Hj7OoIC2glSUpQj4UW1HAcUIMzA%20MiKLHW3bIwGM2AIFNqCIHS3hsG8ftQAoFDYLCofjPsrdHXsfRUEy3UspK7D9yP4D8SAjfQhwTWqnw%20wWDnfkx8XSAUKH%20xbadAz7I8%20h-KBOT5AAnr%204Fv5FFufRHNbjAAYAgAYt0YgQEcjECyuFN%20IggA), with 3 real-time interactive logical switches SP3T;

1. high ESR cap, high DCR L. high Rb to transistor > poor response
2. Ideal LC with DCR=0, ESR=0 (unrealistic but works in theory)
3. low ESR cap, low DCR choke (1 ohm) and more base current with low Rb from 3V.

[image]

When L exceeds saturation current L drops like a rock and loses its stored energy.

- , so duty cycle , Voltage boost ratio and L max current are critial.